# How to match parenthesis in StanfordNLP regexNER?

Tags: regex, stanford-nlp

I want to use StanfordNLP regexner to annotate some data by using dictionary lists. 
Unfortunately I am not able to match parenthesis within a pattern as in :

```
"Iq (mA) max"
```

where the match should be either `"Iq" or "Iq (mA) max"`

I tried different regex, such as

```
Iq(\s\(\smA\s\)\smax)?  
Iq(\\s\\(\\smA\\s\\)\\smax)?
```

but nothing worked.It always just matches the `"Iq"`
Can anyone help? 
Is it possible at all with regex?

Answer (score 1):

Your rule should be formatted this way:

```
Iq -LRB- mA -RRB- max    ENTITY    MISC    1
```

If you want everything after Iq to be optional, I think the easiest thing to do is just write a separate rule with just `Iq`

Each element of the space separated list at the beginning of a RegexNER rule is a regular expression that matches a TOKEN, so if you add question marks you can make some of the tokens in the pattern optional, but I'm not sure there's a way to make them all optional as a group or not.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! What's the effect of the "1" in the rule?  I'm gonna make all patterns optional by adding question marks to each since I couldnt find any solution that would make the whole group optional.